# maven projects managements

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

I need advice, we have three independent projects but some of them share some dependencies and others are context related. Is it better to use inheritance in maven pom or use dependencies?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you mean by "context related".

In general I would recommend you use dependencies if the projects are independent enough.  Inheritance would make sense if they're sharing more that couple of modules.  For example, if all three projects need to use version Y of library X, and you're going to be updating this library at once in all three projects, then use inheritance. Otherwise, I wouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use dependencies. Pom inheritance makes more sense when you have different submodules of the same application, so you want all of the submodules to use the same version of the dependencies.

Comment: thanks @Augusto actually all the three projects are multimodules projects, we wanted to put the shared properties like plugins, repositories... to have some kind of fine grained control over the build of the projects, like if we update a project version and create a new tag for it the other projects are somehow notified of the change of the version

Comment: I think it's a matter of balance between how much you want to reuse in each of the projects, and not defining a lot of dependencies that later get overridden in the child poms (rendering the parent pom useless). I think it makes a **lot** of sense to have a parent pom that defines repositories and plugins that are really shared between all the modules (e.g. Sonar), but again, be careful not to add more things that you actually need. About dependencies, I don't fully like that, as different apps will change dependencies at different rates (eg you want to try JUnit 5 in one of the apps)

Answer (score 0):

You should use dependencies for all dependencies that aren't needed in every  module. If there exist some shared sets of dependencies, like many spring dependencies for example, you can use a [bill of materials](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Importing_Dependencies).